# Cython compiled ok, but Symbol not found: __ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE when running on Mac OS

Tags: python, c++, c++11, clang, cython

System: Mac OS 10.12.6. Python: Python 3.5.2 from Anoconda3. Cython==0.28.

I set up and compiled Cython with

```
# the .pyx file 
from libc.stdint cimport *
cimport CLexActivator
def SetProductFile(filePath):
    cdef bytes py_bytes = filePath.encode()
    cdef const char* c_string = py_bytes
    cdef int32_t status = CLexActivator.SetProductFile(c_string)
    print(status)
    return status
```

and

```
# the setup file
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
ext_modules=[
    Extension("PyLexActivator",
          sources=["PyLexActivator.pyx"],
          language='c',
          extra_objects=["libLexActivator.a"], 
    )
]
setup(
    name = "PyLexActivator",
    ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules)
)
```

I used `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` to compile.

```
Compiling PyLexActivator.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing PyLexActivator.pyx
running build_ext
building 'PyLexActivator' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5
/usr/bin/clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/o/anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -I. -I/Users/o/anaconda/include/python3.5m -c PyLexActivator.c -o 
build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/PyLexActivator.o
/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/o/anaconda/lib -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/PyLexActivator.o libLexActivator.a -L/Users/o/anaconda/lib -o /path to/PyLexActivator.cpython-35m-darwin.so
```

Error occurs when running `import PyLexActivator`

```
dlopen(/path to/PyLexActivator.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): 
Symbol not found: __ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE
Referenced from: /path to/PyLexActivator.cpython-35m-darwin.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /path to/PyLexActivator.cpython-35m-darwin.so
```

I do not know what `__ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE` represents. Since the `.pyx` compiled with a static lib `libLexActivator.a`, I guess this error might come from unknown references. But I do not know how to solve it.

I also use `otool -L` to show

```
PyLexActivator.cpython-35m-darwin.so:
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)
```

PS: If I use `language="c++"`, there is another error `Symbol not found: _kSCPropNetProxiesHTTPPort`.

Comment: That's clang C++ name mangling for `_std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage`. An error like this usually means you compiled some code as C++ but then didn't link with a C++ stdlib. In this case, it's presumably that `libLexActivator.a` that requires the C++ stdlib. If so, the two options are: (1) add `language="c++"` so Cython builds everything as C++, or (2) add the appropriate `libc++` or `libstdc++` or the like as an extra lib.

Comment: Hi, @abarnert when I use `language="c++"`, there is another error `Symbol not found: _kSCPropNetProxiesHTTPPort`.

Comment: That's a different problem. `_kSCPropNetProxiesHTTPPort` is part of the `CoreFoundation` framework, so you're going to need to link _that_ in as well. Rather than going step by step and trying to figure out where each error comes from, is there some documentation on building executables/dylibs against `libLexActivator.a`? If not, is there a Makefile (or whatever build system it uses)?

Comment: @abarnert I think you're probably right. I have successfully used this static lib in Xcode. And I added two extra libs `CoreFoundation.framework` and `SystemConfiguration.framework`. I used `c++` compiler in Xcode.

Comment: OK, that's exactly the same thing you need to do in Cython. I'm pretty sure there is a right way to specify frameworks in the `Extension` constructor in `setup` (rather than pretending they're just weird LDFLAGS), but I don't remember what it is. Try searching, and if you can't find it, I can try too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the missing function is a C++ mangled name. Most compilers nowadays come with tools to demangle, or you can use an online demangler like [this one](http://demangler.com/), which works for all not-too-ancient versions of clang++, g++, and MSVC. The result is `_std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage`.

This is pretty clearly part of the C++ standard library. The problem is that you've compiled some code to use C++ `std::string`, but haven't linked the C++ stdlib. It's not your Cython-generated code, or Python, so presumably it's that `libLexActivator.a`.

The easy fix for this is to [have Cython compile all of your code as C++ instead of C](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#specify-c-language-in-setup-py), by adding `language="c++"` in your `cythonize` call. This is a little more extreme than you need, but it's probably fine.

Alternatively, you can just pick the right C++ stdlib and link to that. That's a bit confusing with clang on the Mac, because there are two of them, `libc++` and `libstdc++`. Recent versions default to the former ([`libc++`](https://libcxx.llvm.org/) is a newer implementation, built by the LLVM/Clang team, to work better with C++11 and later). But if you're building for 10.6, I'm not sure whether that's still right. So you may have to research it (or ask experts on the C++, Mac, and Clang related tags), or just try both and see.

---

From your comments, after you fix that, you get another missing symbol, `_kSCPropNetProxiesHTTPPort`. That distinctive naming style almost certainly means it's a constant exported by something either inside Apple's `CoreFoundation` framework, or one of the other C frameworks sitting on top of it. But don't guess, just paste it in your favorite search engine, and you'll find [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/kscpropnetproxieshttpport?language=objc), which show that it's part of the `SystemConfiguration` framework. So, you need to add that to the build as well.

At this point, it's pretty clear that `libLexActivator.a` isn't just simple C/POSIX code; it's got some platform dependencies (and it may have third-party dependencies too, for all I know) that it needs to link against. So, the best thing to do is to find its documentation and see what linking with it requires. (If there is no such documentation, you should be able to figure it out from the `Makefile` and/or other build tools, but if you don't know how, you should really ask a separately-tagged question for C++ help.)